# Android HttpEntry read hang on Droid x

Tags: java, android, http, inputstream

I've been working on a web-based android app , and we want the app to post data to server and read the response as JSONString , the code was tested on 3 different devices and all result ok , except for Droid X , it just hangs up on reading the inputStream from HttpResponse.
Here is my code :

```
HttpResponse response = mClient.execute(mPost);
StatusLine status_line = response.getStatusLine();
int status_code = status_line.getStatusCode();
/*
 * Not ok Response
 */
if (status_code != 200){
  mBusy = false;            
  mListener.log("Error Status code = "+String.valueOf(status_code));
  return false; 
}

HttpEntity entry = response.getEntity();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
mResponse = reader.readLine();
```

Any ideas what should I do ?

Comment: What is the Android OS version running on Droid X? Are you running these code on UI thread?

Comment: OS is 2.3.4
and no , it is running in a background thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem source was using android's default HTTP Client.
instead I used :

```
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, false);  
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10000);
        ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 100);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, 30000);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http",PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https",PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        ThreadSafeClientConnManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
        mClient = new DefaultHttpClient(manager, params);
```

instead of :

```
mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

hope that helps someone.